# Is it always the case that any one STAR leads to all the runways?

Tags: navigation, approach, sid-star

I was making an addon for a flight simulator and I am having a problem figuring this scenario out:

Let's take CYOW - Macdonald Cartier international.

It has 6 runways: 04, 07, 14, 22, 25, 32.
It has 5 STARs : CAPTL4, DEANS8, LEAMY3, MEECH1, RIVER2.

For this specific airport every STAR can be used to approach runway 07,14,22,25 and 32. (Runway 04 isn't used for arrivals at all.)

I was wondering if this was the case for every airport or is it different? I'm not sure if my wording was right. I'll try to clarify it to the best of my abilities if further clarification is needed.

Comment: I've clarified the title, please check if it matches what you have in mind.

Comment: I think if you look at the example of FRA, some STARs are designed to lead to specific runways. In reality, however, ATC mix and match freely (making it a pain for flight crew to get the flight management computer reflect the actual clearance, as an aside).

Answer (score 6):

Some STARS are designed for specific runways (i.e. not all runways for the airport).

For example, shown below is the BASET FIVE ARRIVAL to Los Angeles.  It is designed for runways 6L/R or 7L/R: (not for runways 24L/R or 25L/R)

**page 1:**
[image]
 **page 2:**

[image]

Comment: @ymb1 - the lighter lines are the transitions, such as HECTOR, JULIAN, PEACH SPRINGS. Both pages constitute the BASET FIVE ARRIVAL STAR.

Comment: Can they approach REEDR (or BASET) at a lower altitude for a westerly landing? Not this STAR, but a different STAR going to REEDR or BASET?

Comment: @ymb1- I suppose anything could be designed.  But REEDR is about 7 miles from the end of 24/25.  This STAR is clearly designed for only the easterly landing direction (rarely used at LAX).  Also note the Lost Comm procedures address the runways involved. Often U.S. STARS do not end at an IAF.  Also, Many airports LAX, SFO, etc. have STARS (and SIDS) that are designed for specific traffic flow directions.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not always the case. Many airports have different STARs from the same point going to different runways.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the STAR, but generally the answer is yes.  You will have to refer to the specific STAR in question.